# The name item does not exist in current context

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am a beginner in C# and trying to build a code but I am getting an error. You can find the code below:

```
string[] sub_directory = Directory.GetDirectories(utils_Analytics);
foreach (string item in sub_directory) 
Console.WriteLine(Path.GetFileName(item.Substring(0,item.Length-10)));
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(item);
```

Comment: The error message is fairly self explanatory. Whatever item it is indicating as out of context doesn't exist where you're trying to reference it. What is your question?

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to Stack Overflow.
You need to create a code block for your `foreach` statement.

```
foreach(condition)
{
    // code here
}
```

Try this:

```
string[] sub_directory = Directory.GetDirectories(utils_Analytics);
foreach (string item in sub_directory) 
{
    Console.WriteLine(Path.GetFileName(item.Substring(0,item.Length-10)));
    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(item); 
}
```

You can use a `foreach` statement without a code block but it only applies to the next one line of code.

```
string[] sub_directory = Directory.GetDirectories(utils_Analytics);
foreach (string item in sub_directory) 
    Console.WriteLine(Path.GetFileName(item.Substring(0,item.Length-10))); // this line is in the foreach
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(item);  // this line is not
```

When you declare the `item` variable in your `foreach` statement, it is only accessible within the scope of the statement (between the {}). The `string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(item);` line is outside of the scope. That's why it throws the error when it tries to access `items`.

Comment: It might help to explain that the reason OP is receiving this error is because `string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(item); ` is not in the `foreach` block and therefore does not have `item` defined.

Answer (score 0):

Your foreach loop is missing {}, the code block should be contained within {}.

In addition, you could try the following code to optimize your code：

```
string[] sub_directory = Directory.GetDirectories(@"...");
        sub_directory.ToList().ForEach
            (
            item =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine(Path.GetFileName(item.Substring(0, item.Length - 10)));
                string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(item);
            }
            );
        Console.ReadKey();
```

If there is an error in Directory and Path, you could add the following reference at the beginning of the code:

```
using System.IO;
```